# Thingsboard: send multiple timeseries in one POST

Tags: thingsboard

I would like to send multiple values in one HTTP POST message to the Thingsboard and display it in plot. Here is an example of JSON data which doesn't work:

```
[
    {
        "ts": 158520169,
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "ts": 158520175,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "ts": 158520180,
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "ts": 158520190,
        "value": 4
    }
]
```

Only last value (4) is saved. Is it possible to send multiple values in one HTTP POST message?

Answer (score 0):

from the Telemetry upload API (here https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/) I can see documented only three ways to post data:

1) JS object with multiple key-value, timestamp assigned by ThingsBoard

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
```

2) JS array cointaining object, one for each key-value

```
[{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}]
```

3) JS object with timestamp and multiple values

```
{"ts":1451649600512, "values":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}}
```

I cannot find any documentation about how to post multiple values with different timestamps (your case).

Maybe you can split your single post into multiple posts?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that ThingsBoard doesn't handle receiving of multiple values with the same key. In my project where devices are connected through GSM, splitting of multiple posts into single post is not possible. One key-value pair is generated every second and sending one POST takes approximately more than 3 seconds. I will probably split data on the server using my own application and pass it to the ThingsBoard. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not mentioned in documentation, it is possible indeed to post multiple timestamped values in one POST query. You may need to format your body as:

```
[{"ts":1451649600512, "values":{"key1":"value1"}}, {"ts":1451649603512, "values":{"key1":"value2"}}]
```

Currently working with 100 items array.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Jorge does work fine. Here's an example of sending 4 different readings for AIN1, and one for AIN2.

```
[
    { "ts": 1632518102000, "values": { "ain1" : 2.41 }},
    { "ts": 1632519002000, "values": { "ain1" : 6.02 }},
    { "ts": 1632519902000, "values": { "ain1" : 3.61 }},
    { "ts": 1632520802000, "values": { "ain1" : 3.62 }},
    { "ts": 1632520802000, "values": { "ain2" : 1.43 }}
]
```

This appears to be a general pattern if you want to ensure a time stamp for every value you send.